# How can I get pysnmp to use pysnmp-mib for friendly output?

Tags: python, snmp, pysnmp

I'm new to both pysnmp and snmp, and I'm trying to get a simple script to dump stats from two routers on my network (an Airport Extreme, and Tomato Firmware router).

This code is (from online examples) works, but without friendly names:

```
from pysnmp.entity.rfc3413.oneliner import cmdgen

cmdGen = cmdgen.CommandGenerator()

errorIndication, errorStatus, errorIndex, varBindTable = cmdGen.nextCmd(
    cmdgen.CommunityData('public'),
    cmdgen.UdpTransportTarget(('router', 161)),
    cmdgen.MibVariable('IF-MIB', '').loadMibs(),
    lexicographicMode=True, maxRows=100,
    ignoreNonIncreasingOid=True
)

if errorIndication:
    print(errorIndication)
else:
    if errorStatus:
        print('%s at %s' % (
            errorStatus.prettyPrint(),
            errorIndex and varBindTable[-1][int(errorIndex)-1] or '?'
            )
        )
    else:
        for varBindTableRow in varBindTable:
            for name, val in varBindTableRow:
                print('%s = %s' % (name.prettyPrint(), val.prettyPrint()))
```

Produces this output:

```
python foo.py

1.3.6.1.2.1.2.1.0 = 8
1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.1.1 = 1
1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.1.2 = 2
....
```

I'm hoping to produce output like snmpwalk:

```
snmpwalk router -c public -v2c

SNMPv2-MIB::sysDescr.0 = STRING: Linux router 2.6.22.19 #20 Tue Apr 2 13:54:22 ICT 2013 mips
SNMPv2-MIB::sysObjectID.0 = OID: NET-SNMP-MIB::netSnmpAgentOIDs.10
DISMAN-EVENT-MIB::sysUpTimeInstance = Timeticks: (55888889) 6 days, 11:14:48.89
....
```

I believe this is just a question of making the MIBs properly available. I have pysnmp-mibs installed, but I haven't yet figured out how to make use of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass

```
..., lookupNames=True, lookupValues=True
```

to your nextCmd() call like [this](http://pysnmp.sourceforge.net/examples/current/v3arch/oneliner/manager/cmdgen/getnext-v2c-with-mib-resolution.html).

For objects that are not in pysnmp-mibs you might need compiling your MIB into pysnmp format and pointing your pysnmp script to it with .addMibSource() method:

```
..., cmdgen.MibVariable('TCP-MIB', 'tcpConnTable').addMibSource('/tmp/mymibs'),
```

as explained [here](http://pysnmp.sourceforge.net/examples/current/v3arch/oneliner/manager/cmdgen/getnext-v1-with-custom-mibs-location.html)